# How to handle Zend SubForms when the number of each is unknown

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a 'customer' form which has a section called 'contacts'. To start with this contacts section will contain the following elements..

```
<input type="text" name="contacts[0][fname]" />
<input type="text" name="contacts[0][sname]" />
```

But the user may want to add another contact which will duplicate the elements with javascript to produce the following:

```
<input type="text" name="contacts[0][fname]" />
<input type="text" name="contacts[0][sname]" />
<br />
<input type="text" name="contacts[1][fname]" />
<input type="text" name="contacts[1][sname]" />
```

I know how to produce the first set of elements, however if the form gets submitted and there are errors, how can i ensure that the correct number of 'contacts' elements get rendered?

Comment: There's a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831145/zend-form-dynamic-adding-subforms , it could be helpful.

Comment: Turns out this is a bug in ZF that is not fixed until v2.0 -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849884/howto-address-specific-element-from-subform-and-have-it-displayed-correctly-with

Answer (score 0):

Ive never had to do this with Zend_Form but i have done it with Symfony 1.4's sfForm which has a similar API and theory of operation. Based on that the basic process is:

1. In the parent forms constructor intialize some default number of subforms. Youll want to separate out the logic for actually creating and embedding `n` subforms into a separate method(s). Ill refer to this as the method `emebedContacts($count = 1)`
2. Override the `isValid` and `setDefaults` methods on the parent form so that they detect the number of subforms in the `$data` arguments passed to them and then call `embedContacts` before calling `parent::isValid()` or `parent::setDefaults()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks, that has helped. I was confused however about how to go about grouping them under the 'contacts' element, but what i ended up doing was creating one empty subform, assigning that as 'contacts' which in turn contained the indexed subforms, and which then in turn contained the fname, sname etc elements.

Comment: Sorry, still having problems - what i've done above sets up the form correctly, however when i try to render the subform elements directly, their names do not appear in array format i.e. they appear as name="fname" rather than name="contacts[0][fname]"

Comment: There is a methos you may need to call manually or pass an option in... i think its something like `Zend_Form::setIsArray` but im not sure youll have to check the docs. Also make sure your passing the second argument to `addSubform` which is the name/key you will later access it with and what will be encode in the `name` attribute of elements.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but i've done all that - the elements render fine if i echo the $form out, but when i echo the subform elements directly the names do not get formatted correctly